# Conditional statements with wait_for for user authentication

Tags: discord, discord.py

### I am trying to make a 'gatekeeper-like' function in which I must approve or reject something.

````
def confirm(m):
    return m.author == 'my id' m.content == 'confirm' or m.content == 'Confirm'

def deny(m)
    return m.author == 'my id' and m.content == 'deny' or m.content == 'Deny'

auth = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=confirm)
deauth = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=deny)

await target.send("```ini\n[Authenticated.]```".format(auth))
await target.send("```ini\n[Denied.]```.format(deauth)"
````

The problem here is simply that I am not sure how I would go about making an if else statement in the function.

**Possible Solutions**

- I am assuming that the if else statement would be a product of mixing both the confirm and deny functions in to one?
- upon looking at the API reference I see that wait_for takes in these arguments: `event, *, check=None, timeout=None`
- what I am assuming could be done is using `try:` and an exception like `asyncio.CancelledError`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a check that looks for either of these messages.  Then once `wait_for` returns the message you can check which content it has

```
def confirm_or_deny(m):
    return m.author.id == id  and m.content.lower() in ['confirm', 'deny']

msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=deny)

if msg.content.lower() == 'confirm':
    ...
else:
    ...
```